# What is wrong with the proof of this statement which is FALSE?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, determinant

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix for $n\geq 2$. Then $\det (A) = 0$.

And the Proof is:

Let $[a_{11}, a_{12},\dotso, a_{1n}]$ and $[a_{21}, a_{22},\dotso, a_{2n}]$ be the first two rows of $A$.

Perform the row operation $R_1 - R_2$ and $R_2 - R_1$ to get

$[(a_{11} - a_{21}), (a_{12} - a_{22}),\dotso, (a_{1n} - a_{2n})]$

In the first row and

$[(a_{21} - a_{11}), (a_{22} - a_{12}),\dotso, (a_{2n} - a_{1n})]$

in the second row.
Then $R_2 = -R_1$ and thus the determinate is $0$.

Comment: You are performing $R_2 - R_1$ and $R_1 - R_2$ **simultaneously**. There is an *order* for these determinant operations, and if you obey that order you will see that these operations do not lead you to the desired conclusion. That is, after performing $R_1-R_2$, $R_1$ has *changed*, so that $R_2-R_1$ is not what you have written down.

Comment: Why downvote  a genuine question?  Arguments that are apparently logical and wrong upon closer scrutiny are the ones we should encourage and point out the fallacy (considering the amount of home work questions we answer this question is that should be asked).

Comment: It is OK to perform row operations simultaneously provided they from a linearly independent set of vectors, Gauss Jordan elimination always produces linearly independent sets, in your example the set containing $R_1-R_2$ and $R_2-R_1 $ is clearly linearly dependent